# I want to print something only once in a while loop in python

Tags: python

Code:

```
while True:
 text = 'fizz'
 if text == 'fizz':
  print('fizz')
 elif text == 'buzz':
  print('buzz')
```

I want to print fizz once if `text = 'fizz'` and if I replace `text = 'fizz'` with `text = 'buzz'` it prints buzz.

Comment: why have a while loop ?

Comment: Add a `break` statement?

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X I suspect the real code does more in the loop.

Comment: Often, if you only want to do something the first time the loop iterates, you can simply move that code to *before* the loop, and adjust your loop condition accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag variable that indicates whether anything has been printed. Don't print again if it's set.

```
printed = False
while True:
    text = 'fizz'
    if not printed:
        if text == 'fizz':
            print('fizz')
            printed = True
        elif text == 'buzz':
            print('buzz')
            printed = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiples ways:

```
printed = False
while not printed:
 text = 'fizz'
 if text == 'fizz':
  print('fizz')
  printed = True
 elif text == 'buzz':
  print('buzz')
  printed = True
```

```
while True:
 text = 'fizz'
 if text == 'fizz':
  print('fizz')
  break
 elif text == 'buzz':
  print('buzz')
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose the outcome of your fizz buzz program use `input()`

**Version 1**

```
while True:
    # Each new loop it starts by asking for fizz or buzz
    # If something other than fizz or buzz is typed in
    # the code will print nothing and loop again
    text = input('fizz or buzz?: ')
    if text == 'fizz':
        print('fizz')
    if text == 'buzz':
        print('buzz')
```

If you want your program to switch between the two each time then use this code

**Version 2**

```
while True:
    text = 'fizz'
    if text == 'fizz':
        text = 'buzz'  # switch fizz for buzz
        print('fizz')
    if text == 'buzz':
        text = 'fizz'  # switch buzz for fizz
        print('buzz')
    # I added a = input() because without it,
    # It would loop hundreds of times a second 
    # printing fizz buzz over and over
    a = input()
```

If you want your code to print one of the two once, then use this code

**Version 3**

```
def fizz_buzz():
    text = 'fizz'
    if text == 'fizz':
        print('fizz')
    if text == 'buzz':
        print('buzz')


printing = True
while True:
    if printing:
        fizz_buzz()
        printing = False
```

Using a procedure makes the while statement a little tidier since having nested if statements and loads in the while loop makes it harder to read.